# Chrome T-Rex-Game Reinforcement learning showing no improvement

Tags: python, machine-learning, deep-learning, reinforcement-learning, q-learning

I would like to create an AI for the Chrome-No-Internet-Dino-Game. Therefore I adapted this [Github-Repository](https://github.com/shivamshekhar/Chrome-T-Rex-Rush)  to fit my needs. I used the following formula to calculate the new Q: [image: Formula]

Source: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Q-learning

My problem now is that even after ~ 2.000.000 iterations my game score is not increasing.

You can find the game file here: https://pastebin.com/XrwQ0suJ

QLearning.py:

```
import pickle
import Game_headless
import Game
import numpy as np
from collections import defaultdict

rewardAlive = 1
rewardKill = -10000
alpha = 0.2  # Learningrate
gamma = 0.9  # Discount

Q = defaultdict(lambda: [0, 0, 0])  # 0 = Jump / 1 = Duck / 2 = Do Nothing

oldState = None
oldAction = None

gameCounter = 0
gameScores = []


def paramsToState(params):
    cactus1X = round(params["cactus1X"] / 10) * 10
    cactus2X = round(params["cactus2X"] / 10) * 10
    cactus1Height = params["cactus1Height"]
    cactus2Height = params["cactus2Height"]
    pteraX = round(params["pteraX"] / 10) * 10
    pteraY = params["pteraY"]
    playerY = round(params["playerY"] / 10) * 10
    gamespeed = params["gamespeed"]

    return str(cactus1X) + "_" + str(cactus2X) + "_" + str(cactus1Height) + "_" + \
           str(cactus2Height) + "_" + str(pteraX) + "_" + str(pteraY) + "_" + \
           str(playerY) + "_" + str(gamespeed)


def shouldEmulateKeyPress(params):  # 0 = Jump / 1 = Duck / 2 = Do Nothing

    global oldState
    global oldAction

    state = paramsToState(params)
    oldState = state
    estReward = Q[state]
    action = estReward.index(max(estReward))
    if oldAction is None:
        oldAction = action
        return action

    # Previous action was successful
    # -> Update Q
    prevReward = Q[oldState]
    prevReward[oldAction] = (1 - alpha) * prevReward[oldAction] + \
                            alpha * (rewardAlive + gamma * max(estReward))
    Q[oldState] = prevReward
    oldAction = action
    return action


def onGameOver(score):
    # Previous action was NOT successful
    # -> Update Q
    global oldState
    global oldAction
    global gameCounter
    global gameScores

    gameScores.append(score)

    if gameCounter % 10000 == 0:
        print(f"{gameCounter} : {np.mean(gameScores[-100:])}")

    prevReward = Q[oldState]
    prevReward[oldAction] = (1 - alpha) * prevReward[oldAction] + \
                            alpha * rewardKill
    Q[oldState] = prevReward

    oldState = None
    oldAction = None

    if gameCounter % 10000 == 0:
        with open("Q\\" + str(gameCounter) + ".pickle", "wb") as file:
            pickle.dump(dict(Q), file)

    gameCounter += 1


Game_headless.main(shouldEmulateKeyPress, onGameOver)
```

On every frame the `gameplay()` function from `Game_headless.py` calls `shouldEmulateKeyPress()`. Said function then returns 0 for Jump, 1 for duck and 2 for nothing.
I tried adjusting the constants, but that didn't show any effect.
If you any questions, please don't hesitate to ask me!
Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Someone on Reddit did this, did you take a look at their code?  https://www.reddit.com/r/MachineLearning/comments/8iujuu/p_tfrex_ai_learns_to_play_google_chromes_dinosaur/

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix the problem, but I don't really know what the mistake was. I added a return statement at the end the gameplay function, and somehow it works now.